# Specify GOOGLE APPLICATION CREDENTIALS in Airflow

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow

So I am trying to orchestrate a workflow in Airflow. One task is to read GCP Cloud Storage, which needs me to specify the Google Application Credentials.

I decided to create a new folder in the dag folder and put the JSON key. Then I specified this in the dag.py file;

`os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "dags\support\keys\key.json"`

Unfortunately, I am getting this error below;

google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: File dags\support\keys\dummy-surveillance-project-6915f229d012.json was not found

Can anyone help with how I should go about declaring the service account key?

Thank you.

Comment: Where are you running airflow, in GCP (Cloud Composer for example) or outside of GCP? And are you using the operators from `apache-airflow-providers-google`?

Comment: I am running it outside GCP (on docker). I am using Python Operator.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a connection to `Google Cloud` from `Airflow` webserver admin menu. In this menu you can pass the Service Account key file path.

[image]

In this picture, the `keyfile Path` is `/usr/local/airflow/dags/gcp.json`.

Beforehand you need to mount your key file as a volume in your `Docker` container with the previous path.

You can also directly copy the key json content in the Airflow connection, in the `keyfile Json` field :

[image]

You can check from these following links :

[Airflow-connections](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/connections/gcp.html)

[Airflow-with-google-cloud](https://junjiejiang94.medium.com/get-started-with-airflow-google-cloud-platform-docker-a21c46e0f797)

[Airflow-composer-managing-connections](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/connections)

Answer (score 0):

If you trying to download data from Google Cloud Storage using Airflow, you should use the `GCSToLocalFilesystemOperator` operator described [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/transfers/gcs_to_local/index.html#airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.gcs_to_local.GCSToLocalFilesystemOperator). It is already provided as part of the standard Airflow library (if you installed it) so you don't have to write the code yourself using the Python operator.

Also, if you use this operator you can enter the GCP credentials into the connections screen (where it should be). This is a better approach to putting your credentials in a folder with your DAGs as this could lead to your credentials being committed into your version control system which could lead to security issues.

Comment: Hi, Thank you. I am actually trying to read files stored in Google Cloud Storage (my first time working with Airflow). I just thought I am able to replicate the same script on my local system as the DAG. I will check the Operator out.