# Google Cloud Platform - How to access service account restricted BigQuery tables through Airflow?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, airflow

So the thing is have got a BigQuery Table 'XX' which my service account don't have access to query it, hence have created a scheduled query which will create a duplicate of that exact same table in my UAT environment where I could query and use that table for coding purposes. likewise, have got multiple scheduled queries.

Now, I'm planning to put up all those scheduled queries under one roof using Airflow Automation by creating BigQuery Orchestration. But the problem I'm facing here is as like scheduled queries - Airflow couldn't access that 'XX' table which my service account doesn't have access to.

Could you suggest what can be done in this case?
My purpose is to replace multiple scheduled queries to single automated one.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Hi @user12345, Are you using Google Cloud Compose?If yes then can you provide the composer and airflow version?<br>

Comment: yes, using composer version 1.19.0 and airflow version 2.2.5

Comment: Hi @user12345,I have provided an answer.If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it.Accepting an answer will help the community members with their research as well.

Answer (score 1):

When you create an environment, you specify a service account. This service account is called the `environment's service account`. Your environment's cluster uses this service account to run pods with different environment components, such as Airflow workers and schedulers. By default, Cloud Composer environments run using the default Compute Engine service account. This Google-managed service account has more permissions than it is required to run Cloud Composer environments.

When you run `Cloud Composer`, it uses a service account. Your workloads are run with this service account and to access the different GCP services, you must ensure that the account has appropriate access rights. You can access the bigquery table by specifying [json key](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/connections/gcp.html#authenticating-to-google-cloud) file also. So to access BigQuery tables through Airflow your service account needs appropriate roles and permission. For more information see these [link1](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/authentication) , [link2](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/access-control) and [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74380932/specify-google-application-credentials-in-airflow).